# Cant locate multiple methods from Apache2::RequestRec

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl

I'm getting multiple errors from Apache2::RequestRec apache, here they are:

`Can't locate object method "args" via package "Apache2::RequestRec" at           /usr/lib/perl5/Apache2/Status.pm line 112.`

OR

`Can't locate object method "uri" via package "Apache2::RequestRec" at /usr/lib/perl5/ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm line 123.`

I'm using mod_perl this way:

`LoadModule perl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so`

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code do:

```
use Apache2::RequestRec;
```

The mod_perl2 API is split into multiple modules.  This has the advantage that you can chose to load only the parts you need and save on memory.  It has the disadvantage that you have to load all the parts you need :-)

See also [ModPerl::MethodLookup](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/ModPerl/MethodLookup.html)

Comment: I tried this  `perl -MModPerl::MethodLookup -e print_method args` but error is still exist.   In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` i have `PerlModule Apache2::Filter Apache2::RequestRec`  what's wrong?

Comment: I do recall running into a problem with things needing to loaded in the right order.  In my apache config I have `PerlRequire /path/to/startup.pl` and then in that file I have `use Apache2::RequestRec;` as well as `use` statements for other parts of the API and my application modules.  The `PerlRequire` in the apache config comes before any Perl handler setup.